# Не заполняется TableView и вылетает NullPointerException

Tags: javafx, tableview

В главном окне программы имеется TableView, в котором будут храниться объекты типа Student(name, subject, mark). При нажатии на кнопку в главном окне появляется новое окно с полями ввода "name", "subject", "mark" и кнопкой "Add". Так вот после нажатия на кнопку "Add" программа вылетает с NullPointerException, и все поля главного окна почему-то равны null. В интернете искал похожие проблемы с tableview, но там в основном были косяки с отсутствием аннотации @FXML у таблицы или fx:id, у меня же все с этим в порядке. В чем может быть проблема?

**Контроллер главного окна**

```
public class Controller {

    private ObservableList<Student> studentsData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private TableView<Student> studentsTable;
    @FXML
    private Button addButton;

    public void addStudentWindow(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        FXMLDocumentController(stage);
    }

    protected void FXMLDocumentController(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("addcontroller.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void addTableItem(String name, String subject, byte mark){
        studentsData.add(new Student(name, subject, mark));
        studentsTable.setItems(studentsData);
    }
}
```

**Контроллер нового окна**

```
public class AddController {

    @FXML
    private Button addStudentInTable;
    @FXML
    private TextField typeName;
    @FXML
    private TextField typeSubject;
    @FXML
    private TextField typeMark;

    public void insertStudent(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        Controller controller = new Controller();
        String name = typeName.getText();
        String subject = typeSubject.getText();
        byte mark = Byte.valueOf(typeMark.getText());
        controller.addTableItem(name, subject, mark);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно дело в том, что при каждом нажатии вы создаёте новый `Controller`, хотя должны были где-то взять ранее проинициализированный.

Comment: @Andrey M, точно, только сейчас обратил внимание. Но как можно получить ссылку на уже созданный контроллер главного окна?

Comment: *"При нажатии на кнопку в главном окне..."* передайте экземпляр контроллера. А так с ходу ответить более точно нет возможности не зная архитектуру приложения.

Answer (score 0):

В общем переписал контроллеры, но данные в таблице не отображались. Добавил метод initialize и все заработало, но только как метод, который я лишь реализовал, но нигде не использовал, смог исправить вывод данных в таблице??

**Контроллер главного окна:**

```
public class Controller {

    private ObservableList<Student> studentsData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private TableView<Student> studentsTable;
    @FXML
    private Button addButton;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Student, String> nameColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Student, String> subjectColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Student, Byte> markColumn;

    public void initialize() {
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("name"));
        subjectColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("subject"));
        markColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, Byte>("mark"));
    }

    public void addStudentWindow(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        Parent root;
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("addcontroller.fxml"));
        root = fxmlLoader.load();

        AddController addController = fxmlLoader.getController();
        addController.parentController = this;

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void addTableItem(String name, String subject, byte mark) {
        studentsData.add(new Student(name, subject, mark));
        studentsTable.setItems(studentsData);
    }
}
```

**Контроллер нового окна:**

```
public class AddController {

    Controller parentController;

    @FXML
    private Button addStudentInTable;
    @FXML
    private TextField typeName;
    @FXML
    private TextField typeSubject;
    @FXML
    private TextField typeMark;

    public void insertStudent(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        String name = typeName.getText();
        String subject = typeSubject.getText();
        byte mark = Byte.valueOf(typeMark.getText());
        ((Node) (actionEvent.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
        parentController.addTableItem(name, subject, mark);
    }

}
```

Comment: Метод `initialize()`, при условии что реализован, вызывается автоматически FXML loader'ом в FX потоке. А так-то это метод интерфейса [Initializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html)

Comment: @Andrey M, спасибо)